# Problem with the with clause when connecting to the wonderware historian database

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-api, common-table-expression

I'm connecting to Wonderware Historian Database on Tableau Desktop through a custom sql query. I'm facing a problem when I use with statement in my query.

```
SELECT DateTime, Compteur, Valeur
FROM
(
SELECT  DateTime, TagName AS Compteur
,       Value - LAG(Value, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY 
DateTime) AS Valeur
FROM History 
WHERE  TagName IN 
                (
                 'H270ME01MDB90.vol',
                'H270ME01MDB91.vol',
                'HA44AC01CDI07.vol',
                'HA44AC01CDI06.vol'
                ) 
AND DateTime >='2018-12-31 23:59:00'
AND wwRetrievalMode='Delta'
)t
WHERE t.DateTime >='2018-12-31 23:59:59'
```

With this code I can get the date from the database but I need to manipulate this data and to do the following:

```
WITH t AS 
(
  SELECT DateTime, Compteur, Valeur
  FROM (SELECT  DateTime, TagName AS Compteur
,               Value - LAG(Value, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER 
BY DateTime) AS Valeur
        FROM History 
        WHERE TagName IN ('H270ME01MDB90.vol', 'H270ME01MDB91.vol', 
'HA44AC01CDI07.vol', 'HA44AC01CDI06.vol'
                          )  AND
              DateTime >='2018-12-31 23:59:00' AND
              wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'
       ) k
   WHERE k.DateTime >= '2019-01-01'  
)
SELECT t.*
FROM t
UNION ALL
(SELECT dateadd(hh,datepart(hh,DateTime), cast(CAST(DateTime as date) as 
Datetime)),
    'K' as compteur,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN Compteur IN ('H270ME01MDB90.vol', 'H270ME01MDB91.vol') 
THEN Valeur END) /
     SUM(CASE WHEN Compteur IN ('HA44AC01CDI07.vol', 'HA44AC01CDI06.vol') 
THEN Valeur
         END)
    ) * SUM(CASE WHEN Compteur IN ('HA44AC01CDI06.vol') THEN Valeur END)
 FROM t
 GROUP BY hour
);
```

It throws an error and says I should put a semicolon before the with statement. When I add it, than it says that there is an incorrect syntax near the ";".
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
[Microsoft SQL error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3saxf.png)

Even this simple with statement doesn't work.

Comment: Wnat is the exact error you get without the `;`?

Comment: This is the error I get without the semicolon: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Are you sure this is MySQL?

Comment: My goal is to get the data and add new rows to the data (without changing the database) by doing some calculations on the existing rows and adding the results to the table.

Comment: This is Wonderware Historian Database and connecting to it with Tableau by choosing Microsoft Sql Server option. By the way LAG() works fine so it should support this kind of things right?

Comment: Please see my edit above in the original post. I inserted a screenshot which is showing the error and the code

Comment: This is what I did, but anyway this was not the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you can't use CTE's in custom SQL queries for Tableau.  Tableau can only use single SELECT statements as SQL data sources.

Comment: Yep, that's what the docs say... https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/using-common-table-expressions. It wraps it in `SELECT TOP 1 * from ( [All your Custom SQL here] ) as [TableauSQL]` hence error

Comment: Thank you Chris Hackett! This was the issue actually. To overcome this problem, before connecting to the database, the "Initial SQL" should be edited. So I'm writing the same code in the Initial SQL. Is it correct to put the same code in the Initial SQL...?

Comment: It looks like you have to change 2 parts:
    
    1.) Put all of your current code (the CTE and the select from)     into the INITIAL SQL box, but your current code needs to     insert into a local temp table name of your choosing (i.e.     SELECT t.* INTO #yourtmptable FROM t....)
    
    2.) In your Custom SQL Query, use something like "select *     from #yourtmptable"